# Specifying JupyterHub Path Variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, jupyterhub

I am in the process of installing jupyterhub.  I successfully install jupyterhub using:

```
python3 -m pip install jupyterhub
npm install -g configurable-http-proxy
```

However, when I run `jupyterhub -h` in the Windows command prompt it gives:

```
"jupyterhub" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.
```

I added `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\` to my user environment variable, however still receive the message.  What path should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that according to [this](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/#a-note-about-platform-support), Jupyterhub is not officially supported for Windows yet.

That aside, you could dockerize it to make your life easier. For this error, please check if you can see the executable in `C:\Program Files\Continuum Analytics\Anaconda3\scripts`. The `lib` directory you're specifying contains python source files and *not* the executables.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and I saw this occurred because `jupyterhub` is a python script rather than an executable. So to run this on Windows I needed to execute it like `python C:\Program Files\Continuum Analytics\Anaconda3\scripts\jupyterhub`.

However, I still was unable to run jupyterhub on Windows because it depends on the `pwd` module, which is a Unix/Linux only module.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Windows is not a supported platform. JupyterHub is best used on Linux-like platforms where you have Docker or something similar to conatainerize each user's session.

A good alternative is to install Oracle VirtualBox and run a local VM. I run a 64-bit Ubuntu and it's quite good performance. It makes things much easier to run JupyterHub on. Asides depending on pwd, there are also assumptions around user-creation and other activities that Windows isn't going to handle well.

In short, if you want to run on native Windows, you're going to become the first JupyterHub Windows contributor. I looked at doing it but it looked like too much effort.

The upside of running a VM is that behaviour in the VM is going to more closely resemble what you have running on the server anyway. If you don't plan running on a server, then just "jupyter notebook", as this is all JupyterHub ends up running...